# Efficient Access SQL to return just one of each unique ClientID from a table

Tags: sql, ms-access-2010, ms-access-2013

I have a list of data with 13 columns.  The column of interest is the ClientID column.  The existing list has multiple rows for each ClientID.  The rows for the same ClientID can differ from each other by values in one or more of the other 13 columns.

What I need is a query that will return just one ClientID from each group of identical ClientIDs.  I do not care which of the rows is returned, but I need to return one and only one of each different ClientID along with the values in the other 12 columns for the row that is returned.

I do have a solution to this problem that works, but my solution seems outrageously cumbersome--i.e., 55 lines of SQL because I have to repeatedly enumerate the columns, do subqueries, do a union, etc.

Is there more efficient Access 2013 (or 2010) SQL to accomplish this elegantly?

Here's a (reduced) dataset like what I'm working with; I start with the following tblClientData:

```
ClientID    Last    First   Sex DOB     AreaCd  Chrt    CtYr    Status  Risk    WNA DpID    SpID
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
6244        Junk    Alpha   F   1952    Null    Null    2014    Assnd   High    BB  1149    Null
6244        Junk    Alpha   F   1952    (333)   Null    2014    Wait    High    DW  1148    901
6244        Junk    Alpha   F   1952    (437)   Null    2014    Wait    Medm    Nul 1130    Null
6253        Jezz    Hejunk  M   1916    (263)   90B3    2013    Refrd   High    NC  1157    901
6253        Jezz    Hejunk  M   1916    (263)   90B3    2013    Closed  Low     NC  1158    703
6287        Fish    Gohh    M   2007    (911)   X117    2008    Assnd   Medm    Nul 1018    807
```

I am hoping for Access 2013 SQL that efficiently produces something like the following (which row is returned is not important so long as one and only one of each ClientID is returned):

```
ClientID    Last    First   Sex DOB     AreaCd  Chrt    CtYr    Status  Risk    WNA DpID    SpID
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
6244        Junk    Alpha   F   1952    (333)   Null    2014    Wait    High    DW  1148    901
6253        Jezz    Hejunk  M   1916    (263)   90B3    2013    Closed  Low     NC  1158    703
6287        Fish    Gohh    M   2007    (911)   X117    2008    Assnd   Medm    Nul 1018    807
```

Comment: Do you want to return one actually existing row?  Or can it be any values from any of the rows which represent the same ClientID?

Comment: In this case, it could be any values from any of the rows which represent the same ClientID.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not familiar with Access SQL, but in most other SQL's, the group by clause is what you should start with

```
Select * from table group by ClientID
```

In Access, it seems that all the columns in the select must be either in the group by list or in an aggregate function, so:

```
Select ClientID, first(Col1), first(Col2) from table group by ClientID
```

is perhaps close to what you want

Comment: Brilliant!  I was not aware of the FIRST function which is what seems to take just the first one of the grouped items.  This is MUCH shorter than the 55 lines of SQL I was using.  The SQL is now just 15 lines. Thank you so much for your help.

Answer (score 0):

select ClientID from yourtable
group by ClientID

Returns only the client id.

Comment: I need to return all the columns, not just the ClientID column.  I just need one row per ClientID but for that one row I need all columns.

Comment: Just be careful on what you use those columns for... you have no idea which row you will be getting, so actual data cannot be relied upon.  I see now that Access has no equivalent of information_schema, so there isn't really a better way to do it if you need the column names.

Comment: Also you can continue to add fields to the group by clause and get the result you want.  `select col1, col2, col3 from table group by col1, col2, col3`